# Best audio classification algorithm for letters phonetics recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, signal-processing, pattern-recognition, audio-processing

this is what i'm doing 
i have the 26 alphabet recorded by 8 personne.
that means i have for evry letter a folder that containt 8 samples of voice reding the letters

Alphabet/A/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Alphabet/B/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Alphabet/C/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
...
Now I want to do classification (supervised learning) on this data set and after that when I give the trained algorithm a sample(audio) of a letter it would return what was that letters

the question is do you know any library that can help or any specific algorithms ?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Deep Learning

shines in audio and image classificarion.

It's what drives Apples Siri and Googles voice recognition as well as Microsoft-Skypes translation.

Right now, this is the one method to use. But you may need much more training data and GPU power.